# Check that the parametrization x(u,v)is conformal if and only if E=G and F=0.

Tags: differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

Check that the parametrization x(u,v)is conformal if and only if E=G and F=0. 
I am slightly confused with what this question is asking me. Could someone please walk me through this question. I believe that for --> we need to choose two convenient pairs of orthogonal directions. However, I am unsure of where to start and how to proceed with this question. 
Thank yoU!

Comment: What is your definition of "conformal"? My own version would be something like "preserves angles between vectors", but perhaps you can be more explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am simplifying notation and being slightly informal. If anything is unclear, I will be happy to clarify.

I will use the notation $$\mathrm{g}(a,b)=a^T\begin{bmatrix}E & F \\ F & G\end{bmatrix}b.$$

Note that the definition of conformal is precisely that $a\cdot b=\lambda\mathrm{g}(a,b)$, for some positive function $\lambda: (u,v)\mapsto \lambda(u,v)$. Thus, if $E=G$ and $F=0$, then $$\mathrm{g}(a,b)=a^T\begin{bmatrix}E & 0 \\ 0 & E\end{bmatrix}b=E^2a^Tb=E^2a\cdot b.$$ Conversely, if $x$ is conformal, then $a\cdot b=\lambda\mathrm{g}(a,b)=\lambda~a^T\begin{bmatrix}E & F \\ F & G\end{bmatrix}b$, so $\lambda\begin{bmatrix}E & F \\ F & G\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$,  so $F=0$ and $E=G=\frac{1}{\lambda}$.

Comment: Thanks! I am confused about the two convenient pairs of orthogonal directions and also how did you get E=G=1/lambda? @RobinGoodfellow

Comment: @Unkle I'm not entirely sure what you mean about orthogonal directions. Perhaps you could define what you mean by that in the original question post? As for how I got $E=G=1/\lambda$, I simply noted that $\lambda$ times the matrix has to be the identity. This implies that the matrix is a scalar multiple of the identity, in particular that $E=G$ and, since $\lambda E=1$, we must have $E=1/\lambda$. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! What does this say about angles measured in the uv plane? @RobinGoodfellow

Comment: The bilinear form $\mathrm{g}$ is kind of like a smoothly varying inner product. If you recall the property of the dot product, $a\cdot b=|a|~|b|\cos\theta_{a,b}$, we can obtain angles by using $\mathrm{g}$ in the similar formula $$\theta_{a,b}=\arccos\left(\frac{\mathrm{g}(a,b)}{\sqrt{\mathrm{g}(a,a)\mathrm{g}(b,b)}}\right).$$

Comment: how would you use the first fundamental form to solve this problem, using the matrix Ip?

Comment: @Unkle -- The bilinear form $\mathrm{g}$ *is* the first fundamental form.

Comment: how would this change if our definition of conformal was angle-preserving? Would the above still be a valid proof? Thanks!

Comment: The definitions are equivalent, so yes. However, you might be expected to do a less enjoyable proof if you are mainly using that definition.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing the proof with that definition. Do you know how to solve it that way or know a source where I could view that proof?

Comment: I do. Above, in the comments, I gave you a formula for the angle between tangent vectors $a$ and $b$. You would show that the angles, provided by that formula, are equivalent to their Euclidean counterparts. The proof, in principle, is the same.

Answer (score 2):

This question seems to be the same as exercise $2.1.6$ on page $42$ in [these nice notes](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf) by Theodore Shifrin on a differential geometry course. I will walk through my solution with that in mind.

The material defines *conformal* on page $40$ as a parametrization that preserves angles: if angles measured in the $uv-$plane agree with corresponding angles in the tangent space $T_PS$ for all points $P$.

We have to fill in with definitions of angles and inner products.

We have a parametrization of the surface $x : U \to S$ with $x = x(u, v)$. Where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$.

Define angle $\theta$ between two vectors x, y by

$x \cdot y = |x||y| \cos \theta$

In $U$ use the usual inner product which means that $x \cdot y = x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2$

In surface $S$ (for vectors of the tangent spaces) use the inner product produced by the first fundamental form (or metric tensor), which means $w \cdot z = \sum_{i, j} g_{ij} w_i z_j$.

Pick a point $Q \in U$ which maps to a point $P \in S$.
Pick two vectors x, y based at $Q$. The vectors map componentwise to $T_PS$ like this: $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto x_1 \mathbf{x}_u + x_2 \mathbf{x}_v$, $(y_1, y_2) \mapsto y_1 \mathbf{x}_u + y_2 \mathbf{x}_v$.  Where $\mathbf{x}_u$ is the partial derivative $$\left.{\partial \mathbf{x}(u,v) \over \partial u }\right|_Q $$, and so on. (Again on page $40$ of the notes.)

Now we can write out the angle in $U$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos \theta_U 
&= { x \cdot y \over |x| |y| } \\
&= { x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2 \over \sqrt{(x_1^2 + x_2^2) (y_1^2 + y_2^2) }}
\end{aligned}
$$

Now we can write out the angle in $S$:

$$\begin{aligned}
\cos \theta_S &= { w \cdot z \over |w| |z| } \\
&=  { Ex_1 y_1 + F x_1 y_2 + Fx_2 y_1 + Gx_2 y_2
 \over 
 \sqrt{(Ex_1^2 + 2Fx_1x_2 + Gx_2^2)(Ey_1^2 + 2Fy_1y_2 + Gy_2^2)} 
} \\\end{aligned}
$$

Where we are using the $E, F, G$ parts of the first fundamental form.

Part 1: Show that if angles are preserved, then $E = G$ and $F = 0$.

Pick these vectors $x = (a, b)$ and $y = (-b, a)$ in $U$ with $a, b \geq 0$, not both zero. These are by design orthogonal in $U$.

$
\cos \theta_U = \dfrac{ x \cdot y}{ \cdots } = 0$  by orthogonality.

We require that $ Ex_1 y_1 + F x_1 y_2 + Fx_2 y_1 + Gx_2 y_2  = 0$ so that the angle in $S$ is correspondingly orthogonal.

We have $Ex_1 y_1 + F x_1 y_2 + Fx_2 y_1 + Gx_2 y_2 = -E ab + Fa^2 - Fb^2 + Gab = 0$.

- Examine the case $a = 1$, $b = 0$ which gives $F = 0$
- Examine the case $a > 0$, $b > 0$ which leads to $(G - E) ab = 0$ and we conclude that $E = G$ (because $ab \neq 0$) to preserve orthogonality.

No further argument is needed for this part. I think this is in the spirit of the hint “pick two orthogonal pairs of vectors” from the question, except slightly more general.

Part 2: Show that if $E = G$ and $F = 0$, angles are preserved.

Use previous expressions for the the angles in $U, S$ and simplify using $E = G$ and $F = 0$. It produces $\cos \theta_U = \cos \theta_S$ because $E$ can be factored from both numerator and denominator and cancels out.